# PHP links in HTML

Tags: php, html

I just have started working with PHP, it seems to be fine so far except for one thing.

**I've changed the links in my html from (for example) `contact.html` to `contact.php`, and for some reason only the link from the homepage to the `contact.php` page is working. If I click on the `contact.php` link from any other page on my site it links me to the `contact.html` file**, which isn't the one I want to use (I want the link to redirect to the PHP page for the sake of the form submission, etc).

If both pages still function the same (it's a simple form submission) I don't mind, but until I can ensure the form is submitting/working as it should (my page isn't hosted yet) I'd like to fix this problem.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT - Here's my code.

```
<form id="form" class="form" action="send.php" method="post">
<li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
```

the link to the contact.php page is the same on every single one of my html pages, except it's only working from the homepage when i run in Apache, while every other page just links to the contact.html page instead.

Comment: And how do you expect us to be able to help without seeing your code?

Comment: Check form action, you probably have `.html` there

Comment: We cannot answer your question till we see your source code.

Comment: You really ought to set up your server such that the suffixes are hidden; that is "/contact" should render your contact page (whether it is implemented as ".html", ".php", ".jsp", or some other means). The server-side language is really an implementation detail and, as such, should be hidden from your users (which includes not leaking that information into your URLs).

Comment: refresh your pages...

Answer (score 0):

it simple you need use the page name where ever u need it for example form

`<form action="contact.php" methode="get" >
..
....
your code
...
</form>`

Comment: What i mean is that the "contact" page itself is .php not .html, i have one of both, but i want every link on my site that used to link to the html page to now link to the php page. I've changed the href's accordingly and have the right form action but they still link to the html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with puting a .htaccess in root

Like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RedirectMatch /index.html /index.php
```

it will redirect your index.html file to index.php